# Silverstripe: Template behavior of "Up"

Tags: silverstripe

In Silverstripe templating, the $Up tag temporarily breaks out of the current loop/with and gives access to the parent scope. While the following template code works, I don't understand why.

$Checked is a list with objects that I loop, in itself containing a list with $Items of which I need to show the first. The object also has an Owner, which I need to access while in the scope of the first item.

I've got the following silverstripe template code:

```
<% loop $Checked %>
    <% with $Items.First %>
        <article class="checked-statement">
            <span class="statement-outcome h-bg-true-$Verdict.Value">$Verdict.Name</span>
            <div class="checked-statement__statement">
                <a href="xxx" class="checked-statement__picture"><img
                        src="$Up.Up.Owner.Photo.CroppedImage(160,160).Url" alt="$Up.Up.Owner.Name.XML" class="h-full-rounded"/></a>
                <a href="xxx" class="checked-statement__name">$Up.Up.Owner.Name</a> zei
                <h3>
                    <a href="yyy" class="checked-statement__statement-text">$Up.Up.Title</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <a href="yyy" class="checked-statement__argument">
                $Up.Up.Statement&hellip;
                $Top.Icon('chevron-right')
            </a>
        </article>
    <% end_with %>
<% end_loop %>
```

I would think I would need only one "Up" to get to the scope of $Checked. But I need two, which is strange, as the first Up should break out of the "with", and the second one should break out of the loop, giving me the top level scope, in which the specific item is not available...

Can anyone point me at the fault in my reasoning, or code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At some point, I believe it was with 3.0 or 3.1, the logic behind $Up changed.

Previously `<% with $Items.First %>` or back in 2.x `<% control $Items.First %>` was just one scope level that you could break out of with $Up.

These days, each object/method call/property gets it's own scope. This means:

```
<% with $Foo.Bar %>Foo's ID: $Up.ID<% end_with %>
<% with $Foo.Bar %>Outside of "with" ID: $Up.Up.ID (== $Top.ID in this case)<% end_with %>

And for deeper nesting you need even more ups:
<% with $Foo.Bar.X %><% loop $Y %>$Up.Up.Up.Up.ID == $Top.ID<% end_loop %><% end_with %>
```

Comment: Ah, so with the first Up I only break out of the First, and end up in the Item list. The second then breaks out of the $Items. That makes sense. Thanks!